# FBX export: object pivot is set to center of the scene

Tags: pivot, blender, unreal-engine4, fbx

Whenever I export my mesh to FBX format (for use inside UE4) its pivot is set to center of the Blender scene (0,0,0), not respecting the original object's pivot position.

Does anyone know why or how to solve this, so that once imported into UE4 object's pivot would be where it should be instead being way off because it is set to original Blender scene center?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the correct answer myself: if you use **File -> Import Into Level** instead of the expected normal Import function, then the import process is a bit different.

It will automatically create Blueprint for you with the root pivot still at the bottom center at 0,0,0 but **now every object in there will have its own original pivot** as seen in Blender...and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior as it allows you to compose scenes consisting of multiple objects in your DCC and have their relative offsets retained, and it gives you easy control over the pivot location of an individual object without having to mess with its hierarchy.

The right thing to do if you're exporting a single object is to place it so the world origin is wherever you want the pivot to be, and then export it.

Comment: I am not exporting one object: I am exporting a LEGO model split into several parts (like canopy, wings, container etc.) that are exported separately but retaining their actual placement in the model so when I am in the UE4 I can grab all of them and once placed into scene (MAP) they are all recreating my model but now I can move every single of them separartelly. My problem tho is that by this I cannot rotate them properly as every single one of them is actually having their pivot (origin) in the center of the original Blender scene, thus my question.

Comment: But I also noticed that if I import it via File menu as a Scene (Blueprint) it still has the pivot in center of the original Blender scene at 0,0,0 but now once in that Blueprint when I click the object it also has it own pivot, so maybe that is the way? You see I'm still only learning UE4 and using Blender just to export my stuff as FBX...